# Android change font - getAssets() error

Tags: android

I have a problem with my custom fonts. I change it like this:

```
@Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate();

    mTimeDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeDisplay);
    Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
            "Fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf");
    mTimeDisplay.setTypeface(typeface);
    mAmPm = new AmPm(this);
    mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    setDateFormat();
}
```

But i have error : `The method getAssets() is undefined for the type DigitalClock`

Comment: Show us your class declaration.

Comment: public class DigitalClock extends LinearLayout {

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're overriding `onFinishInflate`, you're extending a `View` of some kind, it seems.

Try this:

```
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),
        "Fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf");
```

... If that doesn't work:

```
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(mTimeDisplay.getContext().getAssets(),
        "Fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use context.getAssets()

Create field: Context context;

```
public class DigitalClock extends LinearLayout {

Context context;

public DigitalClock(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) 
{

    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    this.context = context;

}
```

}

Then you will be able to access getAssets() via context

Comment: In what class are you implementing onFinishInflate? If it's not in the Activity you should access it through the context. But you have to have defined Context context and then initialized context in the class constructor. Then you should be abble access to getAssets() via context

Comment: public class DigitalClock extends LinearLayout {